# Ruby on rails markdown related issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am a newbie in ruby on rails it's also my first ruby application. Now I need to add markdown in my application I am following the below tutorial

http://crabonature.pl/posts/16-markdown-in-ruby-on-rails

But it's showing an error that is:

[image]

Also here is my codes details

View file code:

```
<%= form_for upload_resumes_path, method: :post do |f| %>
   <div class="col-sm-6">
         <div class="form-group">
             <label class="title">Job Description</label>
             <%= markdown @upload_resumes.job_description %>
         </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Controller code:

```
def uploadResume
   @upload_resumes = current_user
end
```

Application_helper.rb code:

```
 module ApplicationHelper
      def markdown(text)
          render_options = {
               filter_html:     true,
               hard_wrap:       true,
               link_attributes: { rel: 'nofollow' }
           }
           renderer = Redcarpet::Render::HTML.new(render_options)

           extensions = {
               autolink:           true,
               fenced_code_blocks: true,
               lax_spacing:        true,
               no_intra_emphasis:  true,
               strikethrough:      true,
               superscript:        true

            }

            Redcarpet::Markdown.new(renderer, extensions).render(text).html_safe

       end
  end
```

Gem file code:

```
gem 'redcarpet'
```

Someone can help me please where the bug

My rails version: 4.2.5

Comment: Make sure `@upload_resumes.job_description` is returning content, not a `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

offtopic,but highly recomend use gem [better_errors](https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors)
it allows you debug inside your browser :)